# FileUpload control not populating <asp:Image> control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a FileUpload control on my web page that isn't populating the  control like it should. It looked pretty straight forward in doing this but obviously I'm doing something wrong. I'm testing this in my IIS so my Server.MapPath value is "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MWP\Images\Img1.jpg". Here is my code below:

```
    Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Try
        Dim strFileName As String = ""

        Session("filePath") = Server.MapPath("/MWP/Images/") & FileUpload1.FileName

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Session("filePath"))
        img1.ImageUrl = Session("filePath")

    Catch ex As Exception
        strMsg = "btnUpload_Click() - " & ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: `Server.MapPath` returns physical path to the location on the web server. `ImageUrl` requires virtual path suitable for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
img1.ImageUrl = "/MWP/Images/" & FileUpload1.FileName
```

Also, unless you need the file's path somewhere else, you don't need to use Session, just use

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("/MWP/Images/") & FileUpload1.FileName

FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath)
```